# Python top-level package with hyphens in name

Tags: python-3.8, python-module, python-packaging

EDIT?: I finished writing this question and solved it by not using any dots at all. i.e `from x.a.b.c.some_lib import foo`, in my example. Don't know how I didn't try that before, I've been at this for hours. I will still post it in case someone with the same issue finds it helpful. I would still also like to know what causes this problem just for my own enlightenment.

I have a directory which contains pre-existing code in another programming language. It has a hyphenated name. It is split into `src` and `test` directories, and each of those has multiple directories inside, with each directory under `src` having a matching one under `test`. I want to bring some python code into this hyphenated directory, organizing it into its `src` and `test` components, same as the rest. However, I can't manage to use a relative import from the test files to the source files, and I'm pretty sure it's because of the hyphen in the top level directory name. From now on I will refer to a simplified example that I have created which displays the same behavior. This is what that looks like:

```
a-dir-with-hyphens
├── __init__.py
├── main_script.py
├── x
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── a
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── b
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── c
│               ├── __init__.py
│               └── some_lib.py
└── y
    ├── __init__.py
    └── a
        ├── __init__.py
        └── b
            ├── __init__.py
            └── c
                ├── __init__.py
                └── another_lib.py
```

`some_lib.py:`

```
def foo():
        return 1
```

`another_lib.py`

```
from ....x.a.b.c.some_lib import foo

def bar():
        return foo()
```

`main_script.py`

```
from y.a.b.c.another_lib import bar

print(bar())
```

If I use four dots in the import statement in another_lib.py, the error I get is:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'y.x'`

Which indicates that with four dots it's at the `y` package, and that at one level above, it should be at the `a-dir-with-hyphens` package, and should work. However, when I try it with five dots, i.e. `from .....x.a.b.c.some_lib import foo`, I get

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Indicating that even though there is an `__init__.py` file in `a-dir-with-hyphens`, python is refusing to make a package there.

Is there a way around this? Are the hyphens actually the cause of the problem or is there something I'm missing? I'd like to use this structure since it's an existing project, and I can't change the directory name since there's a lot of scripts that point to it. Worst case scenario, I use a different structure just for the python part, but I'd like to avoid that.

I am using Python 3.8